# Hibernate Query using Enum as Parameter

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, enums

I'm having no luck getting a hibernate (using HSQLDB) query to work.  The query code looks like:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from "+tableName+" where CURRENCY = :currency");
query.setParameter("currency",currency);
List<ExchangeRate> list = query.list();
```

I consistently get "Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: incompatible data type in conversion":

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2529)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2512)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2337)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:495)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1275)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at com.rockymountaineer.wsapi.db.test.ExchangeRateDAOTest.getRate(ExchangeRateDAOTest.java:27)
    at com.rockymountaineer.wsapi.db.test.ExchangeRateDAOTest.main(ExchangeRateDAOTest.java:39)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: incompatible data type in conversion
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.throwError(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.setParameter(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.setBytes(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:280)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:612)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1875)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1836)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1816)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:900)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2526)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: incompatible data type in conversion
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.types.NumberType.convertToDefaultType(Unknown Source)
    ... 24 more
```

The class is annotated like so:

```
@Column(name="CURRENCY", nullable=false)
public CurrencyType getCurrency() {
    return currency;
}
```

...and the Enum type looks like:

```
public enum CurrencyType {
    CAD, AUD, EUR, GBP, USD;    
    /**
     * @param currency
     * @return
     */
    public static CurrencyType getByCurrency(String currency) {
        if(currency!=null) {
            for(CurrencyType type : CurrencyType.values()) {
                if(type.name().equals(currency)) return type;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

From what I understand by the Hibernate documentation, this should totally work - not to mention that I am currently able to save, edit, delete, query (by id) objects using other hibernate methods - but the "createQuery" is proving stubborn.

If anyone can help I'd sincerely appreciate it!
Cheers,

Alex

Answer (score 8):

...ok - figured it out.  In case anyone else is confused, here is what I discovered.  It seems that by default, the table is created using the ordinal value (in my case `CurrencyType.ordinal()`) so the column ends up looking like `CURRENCY INTEGER NOT NULL` when the table is created.

This is less than ideal as if I change the Enum type (i.e. the order of the values), this will break everything.  The good news is I can force it to save the `String` value (`CurrencyType.name()`) by adding a `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` to the method, so it will look like:

```
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="CURRENCY", nullable=false)
    public CurrencyType getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }
```

...now to re-enter all the data.